# Создание новой гугл таблицы, при добавлении значения в ячейку очередной строки, имеющейся таблицы

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

есть задача, помогите сообразить. [image: основная таблица]
есть таблица, при добавлении очередного значения в столбец "номер КТК" должна создаваться новая гугл.таблица на гугл.диске с названием введенным в эту ячейку.

как я пытался это сделать: 
 в таблице есть обработчик события по изменению значения в данной ячейке.

```
function onEdit(e){   
   var range = e.range;
   var SCRIPT_URL = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyYoE-Isd--Z_qdqg45345345upp0jroH0k7X3CYDnZ8P1uzw/dev";
  switch(range.getColumn()) { 
    case 2: 
    {
      .....           
    }
```

но т.к скрипт из таблицы не может создавать новые документы на гугл.диске, был создан и развернут как веб-приложение, новый файл GoogleAppsScript который и выполняет эту функцию.

```
 function doGet(e) 
 {
  var folder = DriveApp.createFolder(e.parameter.a1);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create(e.parameter.a1);
  var temp = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId());
  folder.addFile(temp);
  DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(temp);
 }
```

собственно вопрос как по событию OnEdit в таблице выполнить функцию doGet из стороннего скрипта? или может быть это как-то по другому делается?

Comment: Можете объяснить почему "скрипт из таблицы не может создавать новые документы на гугл.диске"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать [UrlFetch.fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object))

Пример использования там тоже есть. Напишу пример с Get и параметром a1 как передаваемый текст:

```
function testGET() {
  // Я так понимаю - это ваша ссылка на web app      
  var SCRIPT_URL = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyYoE-Isd--Z_qdqg45345345upp0jroH0k7X3CYDnZ8P1uzw/dev";
  // Какой-то условный метод - возвращающий нужное вам наименование, которое нужно передать в web app
  var a1 = getNameForCreateFolder_();
  var formData = {
    'a1': a1
  };
  var options = {
   'method'  : 'get',   
   'payload' : formData
  };

  UrlFetchApp.fetch(SCRIPT_URL, options);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, действительно этот способ сработал. Только хочу добавить для тех, кто столкнется с такой-же проблемой. Нужно убедиться что в файле-скрипте к которому вы обращаетесь была необходимая запись Google APIs(посмотреть можно в редактор скриптов->файл->свойства проекта-вкладка данные). Мне например при обращении к скрипту возвращалась ошибка 401 (неавторизован) пока я не добавил строку  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive (чтоб ее добавить вставьте в код и выполните функцию   function authorizeDrive (){var forScope = DriveApp.getRootFolder ();}  после чего дайте гуглу нужные разрешения.